java hashmap : enexpected behaviour for containsKey
Here is a code snippet :
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final byte key = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put(0, 10);
    System.out.println(test.containsKey(key));
}

and I get false printed on console. Only if I cast key to int I get true, like this
System.out.println(test.containsKey((int)key));

Can someone explain what is going on here?

This question is similar to: Will HashMap's containsKey method in java, check for an integer if I put a character in it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Boxing
put takes an Integer as the key. So the primitive numeric literal 0 in put(0, 10) gets boxed to an Integer object.
But containsKey takes an Object (see also). So the byte gets boxed to a Byte object. This Byte object does not equals the Integer object that was put into the map since they are completely different classes. Therefore containsKey returns false.



Primitive type
Object type, after auto-boxing




int
java.lang.Integer


byte
java.lang.Byte




See Auto-boxing, at Wikipedia. And Autoboxing tech note at Oracle.com.

Note to reader: The key concept here is rather subtle. The trick lies in the fact, as covered in this Answer, that put takes a specific type  while containsKey does not take a specific type, instead taking just Object.  Why doesn’t containsKey & get take a specific type? The reason has to do with technical limitations when Generics was added to later versions of Java. I recently saw this discussed in a Question on Stack Overflow, but I cannot find it now.
